# How do I add a date string to a URL?

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, url

I have some code that gives today's date as a string using

```
currnetdate = (pd.datetime.now().date())
```

and then in the URL, I have

```
main_api = 'https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/_a/flights/?query=&flightType=departure&terminalType=domestic&date=' + currnetdate + '&sortColumn=scheduled_time&ascending=true&showAll=true'
```

now when i run the code i keep getting a error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.date") to str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
str(currnetdate)
```

To convert the datetime object to a string. You could also use f-strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate `date` to `str`. If you use Python 3.6 or newer use f-string

```
main_api = f'https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/_a/flights/?query=&flightType=departure&terminalType=domestic&date={currnetdate}&sortColumn=scheduled_time&ascending=true&showAll=true'
```

otherwise cast `currnetdate` to `str`

```
main_api = 'https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/_a/flights/?query=&flightType=departure&terminalType=domestic&date=' + str(currnetdate) + '&sortColumn=scheduled_time&ascending=true&showAll=true'
```